# Multi-dimensional array traversal with Symfony Form Validation

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, traversal

I have an array of multi-dimensional array that represents my form each level represents a child form until you get to a field.

I want to be able to traverse that array keeping track of where of where I have been so I don't go down the same route more than once.

Each array key is essentially a `$form->get($key)`. There are a couple of fields that are named identically but are down different routes (highlighted in red in the below image).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What stops you from simply iterating the array?

Comment: It would have to be a recursive function?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my fix. I created a form map which consists of the number of fields each with child arrays for the path to the element and the error.

I then loop over them and pass them through Symfonys `mapViolation` method in `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\ViolationMapper\ViolationMapper`.

Here is complete class:
https://gist.github.com/linxlad/3ec76c181f717fba532bf43484b7c970